# Too many re-renderds | React App | State Variables updated in Component Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mern

### Problem Summary

I am working on a React app with Node.js, Express.js, MogoDB backend.

I have a progress bar component. The number (i.e. percentage) that I pass to the progress bar comes from a function. This function calculates the percentage of the progress bar and then updates the state variable "progress".

The problem is that I seem to have an infinite re-rendering error. However, I cannot tell where it originates from and how to approach it.

### Problem Description

**Progress Component**

Consider the following react component. This component is a progress bar. The component takes a float `done` and then shows a progress bar with a bar that takes up `done`% of the progress bar space

```
const Progress = ({done}) => {
  return (
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-done" 
        style={{
          opacity: 1,
          width: `${done}%`
        }}>
        {done}%
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Use of Progress Bar in App.js**

I attempted to implement the progress bar like below:

```
const App = () => {

    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0)
           const [groupOfTasks, setGroupOfTasks] = useState([])

    // assume that there’s code here that sets groupOfTasks using data from a database

    const countDone = (groupOfTasks) => {
        var numOfTasks = groupOfTasks.length
        var numOfTasksSatisfied = 0

            groupOfTasks.map((task, index) => {
                if(task.completed == True)
                      {
                          numOfTasksSatisfied++
                      }
           }
           setProgress(numOfTasksSatisfied/numOfTasks)

    }
    
    
    return (
        {countDone(groupOfTakss))
        <Progress done={progress}/>  
    )
}
```

but I got this error:

[image]

**How would you recommend I approach this problem? Any help is very appreciated**

Comment: where do you call countDone function? is it inside useEffect hook?

Comment: You need to invoke the `setProgress` with **parentheses** instead of square bracket. parentheses. Change to `setProgress(numOfTasksSatisfied/numOfTasks)`

Comment: I call the `countDone` function above the `<Progress/>` component. I realized I used `setProgress` while writing my question; I corrected it, but in my I code I had been using parentheses all along. Thanks for the catch

Comment: You should be invoking the  `countDone` inside a `useEffect` hook.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using the countDone inside the return (where the visual render should be done)
You should use the useEffect hook, with the groupOfTasks as dependency.

So whenever the groupOfTasks is updated, you can have the progress updated at the same time

Just after you countDone method

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    countDone(groupOfTasks)
  },[groupOfTasks])
```

By the way if you want to understand a bit more about the useEffect here a great [article](https://daveceddia.com/useeffect-hook-examples/#:%7E:text=When%20you%20call%20useEffect%20in,one%20of%20them%20has%20changed.) !

Answer (score 0):

The error comes due to the line `{countDone(groupOfTrasks)}` inside the return statement. This is what happens:

You -> Render App -> Calculate count -> The countDone function sets a state, so it will rebuild the App -> Render App -> loop...

You can come over this problem by using the hook `useEffect`. The hook works like this: it takes a block of code and then an array.

If the array is empty -> the code will be executed only once when component is rendered.
If the array has variables -> the code will be executed every time one of those variables changes.
This is called dependencies array. In your case, set `groupOfTasks` inside the array, and it means: "Every time groupOfTasks changes, execute this code".
The function will be:

```
const App = () => {

    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0)
    const [groupOfTasks, setGroupOfTasks] = useState([])

    // assume that there’s code here that sets groupOfTasks using data from a database

    const countDone = (groupOfTasks) => {
        var numOfTasks = groupOfTasks.length
        var numOfTasksSatisfied = 0

            groupOfTasks.map((task, index) => {
                if(task.completed == True)
                      {
                          numOfTasksSatisfied++
                      }
           }
           setProgress(numOfTasksSatisfied/numOfTasks)

    }
    useEffect(()=>{
       countDone(groupOfTasks)
    },[groupOfTasks])
    
    return (
        <Progress done={progress}/>  
    )
}
```